# How to avoid "Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group" error when using REGEXP_EXTRACT()

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract a parameter from a field. Unfortunately, this parameter can comes in two flavors of `key=value`. The first uses key = "ch" (e.g. `foo.com/bar?ch=facebook`) and the second uses key = "cid" (e.g. `foo.com/bar?cid=facebook`).

I tried to extract these params using

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(page_url, r'(ch|cid)=([A-Za-z]+)') as channel
```

However, this gives me the error

```
Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group
```

which makes sense.. Is there nice solution to this problem, other than something like

```
case 
  when REGEXP_CONTAINS(page_url, 'ch=') then REGEXP_EXTRACT(page_url, r'ch=([A-Za-z]+)')
  when REGEXP_CONTAINS(page_url, 'cid=') then REGEXP_EXTRACT(page_url, r'cid=([A-Za-z]+)')
end as channel
```

Comment: `r'(?:ch|cid)=([A-Za-z]+)'` - use a **non-capturing** group for the alternatives you do not need to extract.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Appreciate the help fellas. Was unaware of non-capturing groups and I failed to google my way into finding that.